# How to set where the x-axis line is drawn in swift charts (line chart)?

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I am using Charts for swift in my iOS application. I currently have it set where only the x-axis line is showing and I want to set at what y value that x-axis line is drawn. To put it into context, I am making a stock chart and want to set the x-axis line to the first value (open price) for the stock. Here is my current line chart view.

Edit: Right now the line is always drawn to the top of the view.

```
let chartView: LineChartView = {
    let view = LineChartView()
    view.noDataText = ""
    view.legend.enabled = false
    view.legend.textColor = .clear

    //X Axis
    view.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true
    view.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    view.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    view.xAxis.axisLineColor = .white
    view.xAxis.axisLineDashLengths = [2]
    view.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    //Y Axis
    view.rightAxis.enabled = false
    view.leftAxis.enabled = false
    view.leftAxis.gridColor = .clear
    view.rightAxis.gridColor = .clear
    view.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

    view.leftAxis.axisMinimum = points[0] //HERE

    return view
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using an additional data set is the simplest way to draw a horizontal line on the chart.

```
    var xMinValue: Double = 0 // use your own value
    var xMaxValue: Double = 12 // use your own value

    var yFirstValue: Double = 9  // set your open price

    let horizontalLineDataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = [
        ChartDataEntry(x: xMinValue, y: yFirstValue),
        ChartDataEntry(x: xMaxValue, y: yFirstValue)
    ]

    let horizontalLineSataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: horizontalLineDataEntries, label: nil)
    horizontalLineSataSet.setColor(.blue)
    horizontalLineSataSet.lineWidth = 2
    horizontalLineSataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    horizontalLineSataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

    chartData.addDataSet(horizontalLineSataSet)

    chartView.data = chartData
```

[image]